# Get list of input names and values from HTML field set in Django

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

Using Django I'm looking for a good way to get the input values and names of type=hidden from a template HTML. I understand the request.POST.getlist method would return a list of all inputs with the same name value. But I actually need to get all the names as well as the values. i.e.,

HTML Code:

```
  <fieldset class="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="testName" value="0" id="processed-input" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Rotate" class="submit" />
</fieldset>
```

And I need to get a list of related names and values. For this case, testName:0.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's what `request.POST` is: a mapping of all names to values.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to get the inputs from that particular field set or of type="hidden"? thanks for your help

Comment: No. The browser doesn't send that information, so there is no way to know it.